# overfull hbox for paracol inside multicol

Tags: multicol, paracol

I use the [paracol](https://ctan.org/pkg/paracol?lang=en) environment to create a twocolumn layout. Then, I'd like to have this layout spread over two columns.
because paracol does not nest, i use [multicol](https://ctan.org/pkg/multicol?lang=en) wrapped around the paracol (`\newentry`), see the MWE below.

For the most part this works as expected. However, there is an overfull hbox warning and, indeed, one can notice the misalignment between the entries inside and outside the multicols environment.

Somehow the proper amount of space is reserved (notice the `\dotfill` alignment), but the text in the first paracol column "thinks" it doesn't have enough space. After removing the tilde `~\hfill`, there is even a linebreak inserted.

I figure it has to do with the way paracol calculates its spacing, but tests with locally modifying the `\textwidth` didn't do any good.

does anyone more knowledgeable have an idea what is going on here?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{multicol}

\def\subqmarginwidth{8em} % entry margin
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5em} % for paracol as well as multicol package..

\newcommand{\newentry}[2][]{%
\setcolumnwidth{\subqmarginwidth,\fill}
\begin{paracol}{2}
#1p~\hfill a)%
\switchcolumn%
#2%
\end{paracol}%
}

\begin{document}

\newentry[2]{some text}
\newentry[2]{\dotfill}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\newentry[2]{\dotfill}
\columnbreak
\newentry[2]{\dotfill}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

output:
[image: MWE output]

Comment: do you need paracol at all here? isn't your `newentry` more naturally  `tabular` or two `\parbox`?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle good question, its been a long ride so i dont remember all the details. `tabular` used to give unsatisfactory results. `\parbox` is ofcourse the natural solution, but i had issues regarding "fitting" the boxes on the line, the box padding/margins, and having several boxes below one another. These issues were solved by the `paracol` environment very neatly.

Comment: I haven't traced but nesting paracol and multicol (essentially two separate two-column implementations) seems very brave, I'm more surprised it works at all than that it sometimes fails. That's not to say a tweak can't make it work but...

Comment: Well yes, i didnt expect it to work either (especially after `paracol` explicitly not allowing nesting), but im not sure what im more surprised about, the fact it works or the way it fails