# Can I get multicols nested in paracol to overflow neatly onto next page?

Tags: multicol, paracol

I'm trying to put main text on the left part of the page, and annotations on the right. In the main text, once the end of the page is reached, it should continue onto the next page, in the same column. For the annotations, I'd ideally like multiple balanced columns, like you would get with multicols.

I get the impression that using multicols inside paracol is dicey [(someone mentioned here that paracol doesn't allow nesting)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/662496/overfull-hbox-for-paracol-inside-multicol). However, it does seem to work reasonably well unless my annotation text is long enough to run onto the next page. In this case, it doesn't run onto the next page, it runs onto the previous one (second example below). Is there some way to set it up to overflow neatly into the same multicol setup, but on the next page?

Here is what I've tried. There's a comment in the second annotation bit where if I extend the text (in this example, extend the lipsum) I get this overflow issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[papersize={17in, 11in}, left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\newlength\defaultparindent
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength\defaultparindent{\parindent}}

\begin{document}

\setcolumnwidth{6.5in,8.3in}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\definecolumnpreamble{1}{\scriptsize \setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount} \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}}
\definecolumnpreamble{0}{\normalfont \normalsize \setlength{\parindent}{\defaultparindent}}

\section{Introduction}

\switchcolumn[0]*
This is the beginning of the main text. \lipsum[1-7]

\switchcolumn[1]
\begin{multicols}{3}
These long annotations belong with the first paragraphs of the main text. \lipsum[1-3]
\end{multicols}

\switchcolumn[0]*
This is more main text. \lipsum[8-9]

\switchcolumn[1]
\begin{multicols}{3}
These long annotations belong with the next part of the the main text. If I were to make this part long enough to overflow the page, it doesn't continue onto the next page as desired; instead the annotations appear on the preceding page. \lipsum[10-12]
\end{multicols}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Here is an example with the desired effect, more or less.
[image: An example of what it should look like.]

And here is an example of it going rather wrong:
[image: Annotations too long for page!]

Comment: To achive balance with paracol one would have to experiment with column widths.  Either that or add gaps in some of the columns.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, thank you for helping me clarify my question. I'd like to have static column widths, and just have the annotation text overflow across right-side columns to take up as much space as is needed. While auto-balancing would be ideal, it doesn't actually have to be balanced. On the other hand, overflowing onto the previous page (like it does in the example) is not what I'm looking for; I'd like it to overflow onto the next page once the annotation columns are full.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but the columns of paracol do not have to all be the same width.  See `\setcolumnwidth` on page 16.  The last column will always fill out to `\textwidth` (automatically).  You can sync up the columns between paragraphs using `\switchcolumn*`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I think my original example was over-simplified; I hope this new example is an improvement to help express what I'm looking for!